# create validation for offset in importing csv file in mysql and php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

hi guys how can i create a validation so that when i import a csv file it will not give me a error offset(intentionally reduced the csv file column)
i got the code https://www.webslesson.info/2016/10/import-csv-file-data-into-mysql-database-using-php-ajax.html

here is the code in index.php

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY id desc";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Import CSV File Data into MySQL Database using PHP & Ajax</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
                <h2 align="center">Import CSV File Data into MySQL Database using PHP & Ajax</h2>  
                <h3 align="center">Employee Data</h3><br />  
                <form id="upload_csv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                     <div class="col-md-3">  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Add More Data</label>  
                     </div>  
                     <div class="col-md-4">  
                          <input type="file" name="employee_file" style="margin-top:15px;" accept=".csv"/>  
                     </div>  
                     <div class="col-md-5">  
                          <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload" style="margin-top:10px;" class="btn btn-info" />  
                     </div>  
                     <div style="clear:both"></div>  
                </form>  
                <br /><br /><br />  
                <div class="table-responsive" id="employee_table">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                               <th width="25%">Name</th>  
                               <th width="35%">Address</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
                               <th width="20%">Designation</th>  
                               <th width="5%">Age</th>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                          ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["gender"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["designation"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
           $('#upload_csv').on("submit", function(e){  
                e.preventDefault(); //form will not submitted  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"import.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:new FormData(this),  
                     contentType:false,          // The content type used when sending data to the server.  
                     cache:false,                // To unable request pages to be cached  
                     processData:false,          // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false  
                     success: function(data){  
                          if(data=='Error1')  
                          {  
                               alert("Invalid File");  
                          }  
                          else if(data == "Error2")  
                          {  
                               alert("Please Select File");  
                          }                       
                          else if(data != 'Error1' && data != 'Error2')  
                          {  
                               $('#employee_table').html(data);
                               alert("Data Import Successfully");                              
                          }  
                     }  
                })  
           });  
      });  
 </script>
```

and here is for import.php

```
<?php  
 if(!empty($_FILES["employee_file"]["name"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");  
      $output = '';  
      $allowed_ext = array("csv");  
      $tmp = explode(".", $_FILES["employee_file"]["name"]);
      $extension = end($tmp); 
      if(in_array($extension, $allowed_ext))  
      {  
           $file_data = fopen($_FILES["employee_file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');  
           fgetcsv($file_data);        
           while($row = fgetcsv($file_data))  
           {               
                $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[0]);
                $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[1]);  
                $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[2]);  
                $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[3]);  
                $designation = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[4]);  
                $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[5]);                
                $query = "  
                INSERT INTO tbl_employee  
                     (id,name, address, gender, designation, age)  
                     VALUES ('$id','$name', '$address', '$gender', '$designation', '$age')  
                ";              
                mysqli_query($connect, $query);             
           }       
           $select = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY id DESC";        
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select);  
           $output .= '  
                <table class="table table-bordered">  
                     <tr>  
                          <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                          <th width="25%">Name</th>  
                          <th width="35%">Address</th>  
                          <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
                          <th width="20%">Designation</th>  
                          <th width="5%">Age</th>  
                     </tr>  
           ';  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["address"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["gender"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["designation"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>  
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
           $output .= '</table>';  
           echo $output;  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'Error1';  
      }  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      echo "Error2";  
 }  
 ?>
```

i put all the code so that every one can try it too.

Thanks for answer

Comment: So are you trying to say you want to validate the file to make sure there are enough columns, or allow a flexible number of columns? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @JonStirling just to make sure that the column are enough and to prevent the offset error.

Comment: Try `isset()` to make sure the column exists?

Comment: So you could always assign `fgetcsv($file_data);` to a variable and test the column count with count().

Comment: @JonStirling completely honest i don't what you mean

Comment: @JonStirling do you mean count in mysql ?

Comment: @aynber where should i use isset()

Comment: No, count() the number of elements in the array returned by the first `fgetcsv` call, that will tell you the number of columns in that line (which I assume is the headers since you disregard it), which you can then test with an `if` to make sure the number is 6, e.g. `if(count($firstRow) === 6) { do something } else { fail }`

Comment: @JonStirling $firstRow ?

Comment: @JonStirling i try the count but still not working